# Why is my markup wrong? - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a template that I am creating that looks like this:

```
  = link_to_function "#{image_tag('platform/icons/add.png')} Add another choice".html_safe, id: 'new-survey', tabindex: -1 do |page|
    = f.fields_for :survey_choices, SurveyChoice.new do |sc|
      - page.insert_html :bottom, 'survey-choices', partial: 'admin/survey_choices/form', locals: { form: sc }
```

But here is the markup that it is creating:

```
<a href="#" onclick="{:id=>"new-survey", :tabindex=>-1}; return false;"><img alt="Add" src="/assets/platform/icons/add.png"> Add another choice</a>
```

Why is my id not being rendered on the page properly?  My `js` function is not able to attach to it?  What do I need to do make this render correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The part `id: 'new-survey', tabindex: -1` is treated as a Javascript function.

Change your `link_to_function` call and add the actual function before the options. Something like this:

```
link_to_function "#{image_tag('platform/icons/add.png')} Add another choice".html_safe,
  'YOUR JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION CALL HERE', id: 'new-survey', tabindex: -1
```

Comment: I have all my javascript at the bottom of the page with the `:javascript` tag.  How do I call a function from within the Ruby?  I would rather be able to attach directly to the `id="new-survey"`.  Can I do that?

Comment: Attaching it to the ID would be the more elegant solution. Just use `link_to` instead of `link_to_function`, use `#` as link target and attach a listener using JQuery to the element.